# Android Dagger @Injects are null

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

Dagger is kicking my butt.

I have the following layout.

- A MainActivity which is injected into the Object graph.
- The MainActivity @Injects a MainPresenter interface. This is Provided via the MainModule which returns a concrete implementation.
- The concrete MainPresenter implementation takes a FileContentInteractor interface. This is provided in the InteractorModule which returns a concrete FileContentInteractor implementation.
- MainModule can do this because it includes InteractorModule.class

Up until now everything is great. From this point on is where it gets tricky.

The concrete FileContentInteractor implementation injects some member variables using @Inject. These member variables are all interfaces which are provided concrete implementations via their respective modules.

An example is @Inject ThreadExecutor threadExecutor. I thought that this would be provided because;

- InteractorModule includes ExecutorModule.class.
- ExecutorModule.class @Provides a concrete implementation of ThreadExecutor in the form of a TaasExecutor object.
- TaskExecutor object has no injected dependencies.

When I run my app and the MainActivity opens the following happens;

- MainActivity calls a method of MainPresenter implementation - works fine!
- MainPresenter has a FileContentInteractor implementation and calls a method on it - works
- The method in FileContentInteractor implementation tries to call a method in ThreadExecutor implementation (which is @Injected as a member variable). This failed because the @Injected ThreadExecutor implementation is null.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

Ok so it turns out I was kicking my own butt...

I was referencing the concrete classes with my @Inject members but using the Interfaces as my @Provides.

Amending the @Inject members from classes to interfaces fixed it.